# Why do shuffling the rows of the dataset is too much dropping the MLPClassifier accuracy?

Tags: scikit-learn, sample, text-classification, multilabel-classification, mlp

Task is to classify text to labelled classes.   (Class labels are: 1, 2, ..., 40)

For this task, text is being encoded first using [sentence transformer](https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/sentence-t5-base) and then [MLPClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html) is used for classification.

The accuracy score received is 0.02 when the dataset is shuffled and 0.52 when dataset is not shuffled.

The code snippets of the code is as follows:

***Step-1***:  Loading and extracting the text and class labels from train and test dataset csv.

```py
#load training data from csv
trainData = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
trainData = trainData.sample(frac=1) # <-- Shuffle the training data rows (It reduces the accuracy score from 0.52 to 0.02 ??)

#Load test data from csv
testData = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
testData = testData.sample(frac=1)  # <---- Shuffle the testing data rows (It reduces the accuracy score from 0.52 to 0.02 ??)

# Extracting the text and label from train data
X_train_text = trainData["text"]
y_train = trainData['label']

# Extracting the text and label from test data
X_test_text = testData['text']
y_test = testData['label']
```

when I do shuffle the train and test data in the above code snippet the accuracy score decreases from 0.52 to 0.02

```py
trainData = trainData.sample(frac=1)  # <-- Shuffle the training data rows (It reduces the accuracy score from 0.52 to 0.02 ??)
testData = testData.sample(frac=1)  # <---- Shuffle the testing data rows (It reduces the accuracy score from 0.52 to 0.02 ??)
```

#### The below code is shared for better understanding the after steps followed (if needed).

***Step-2***:  Encoding the sentence using [sentence transformer](https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/sentence-t5-base).

```py
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
model = SentenceTransformer('sentence-t5-base')

X_train_emb = model.encode(X_train_text)
X_test_emb = model.encode(X_test_text)
```

***Step-3***: The encoded text is then trained on [MLPClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html) for classification and printing the accuracy score as follows:

```py
#initialise the  MLP Classifier
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
clf = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(64,32), activation="tanh", learning_rate='adaptive',  max_iter=1000)

model_mlp = clf.fit(X_train_emb,y_train)
model_mlp.score(X_test_emb, y_test)
```

Why the accuracy is changing so much from 0.52 to 0.02, just by shuffling the dataset?

Comment: This is not a programming question, you could ask on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/. I'm not sure the reason but 1) are the 40 classes balanced? Because if not, it's a mistake to use accuracy. For example if you have a class which is 50% of the test accuracy can be 0.5 just be always predicting this class. 2) it's likely that there is some data leakage in the non-shuffled case, possibly because there is a specific order causing duplicates in the training/test set. Also 0.02 is lower than the random baseline with 40 classes: 1/40=0.025, it's strange.

Comment: Basically there are lots of basic things that you should investigate in order to understand these weirld perf values.